# Remover um elemento por vez com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Estou utilizando a função *Clone* do jquery para poder replicar uma *div*. Porém, ao remover esses elementos, independente da quantidade que tenha sido replicado, sempre a função remove a *div* por completa. Preciso que seja removido linha por linha.

Código do formulário:

```
<div class="row">
<a class="btn btn-info btn- pull-right" id="add-more-btn" title="Adicionar mais arquivos">Adicionar</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-circle pull-right" id="remove-inputFile-btn">-</a>
</div>
<div class="row arquivo_upload" id="uploadArquivoId">
<div class="col-md-6" >
    <?= $form->field($model, '[0]descricao')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 ">
    <?= $form->field($model, '[0]arquivo_url')->fileInput()?>
</div>
```

```
$('#add-more-btn').on('click', function() {
var clone = $('#uploadArquivoId').clone();
var cloneInput = clone.find('input');
var index = $('.arquivo_upload').length;
$(cloneInput[0]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][descricao]')
$(cloneInput[1]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][arquivo_url]')
$(cloneInput[2]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][arquivo_url]')
$('#row-clone').append(clone);
});

$('#remove-inputFile-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('#row-clone').remove();
});
```

Comment: Ao clonar `$('#uploadArquivoId')` vc vai repetir o id, o que é incorreto.

Comment: Mas é por ele que seleciono o elemento que vou clonar, no caso, a div por completa.

Comment: Vc pode selecionar pela classe.

Comment: Tentei pela classe:   var clone = $('.row arquivo_upload').clone();  Mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao clonar o elemento `<div class="row arquivo_upload" id="uploadArquivoId">` será duplicado o `id="uploadArquivoId"`, o que torna incorreto seu HTML, porque um `id` deve ser único na página.

Selecione o elemento pela classe `.arquivo_upload` e apenas o primeiro com `:first`:

```
var clone = $('.arquivo_upload:first').clone();
```

Remova o `id` que não vai ter mais utilidade, ficando apenas:

```
<div class="row arquivo_upload">
```

No evento para remover os elementos, use o seletor `:last` buscando o último elemento clonado. Ao usar `$('#row-clone').remove();` você está removendo a div que recebe os clones toda:

```
$('#remove-inputFile-btn').on('click', function() {
   $('#row-clone .arquivo_upload:last').remove();
});
```

**Veja um exemplo:**

```js
$('#add-more-btn').on('click', function() {
   var clone = $('.arquivo_upload:first').clone();
   var cloneInput = clone.find('input');
   var index = $('.arquivo_upload').length;
   $(cloneInput[0]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][descricao]')
   $(cloneInput[1]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][arquivo_url]')
   $(cloneInput[2]).attr('name', 'ArquivoDocumental['+index+'][arquivo_url]')
   $('#row-clone').append(clone);
});

$('#remove-inputFile-btn').on('click', function() {
   $('#row-clone .arquivo_upload:last').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
   <a class="btn btn-info btn- pull-right" id="add-more-btn" title="Adicionar mais arquivos">Adicionar</a>
   <a class="btn btn-warning btn-circle pull-right" id="remove-inputFile-btn">-</a>
</div>
<div class="row arquivo_upload">
   <div class="col-md-6" >
       <input>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 ">
       <input>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="row-clone"></div>
```